# What Photoshop does with pixels at "Hue +15" operation?

Tags: colors, photoshop

I need to do same effect on pictures in my program, but I don't understand the rules on how PS decide which pixel component to change and how much.
At some pixels I see -30 components changes, while at other there are -2 - +2 changes.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "color tone -15". By component change, do you mean RGB components, or HSL, or Lab? In short we need more info.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - I don't know anything about HSL or Lab. I found that I wrote this operation name by mistake. From my language it translates as "Color tone", while in English it's just "Hue". I uploaded  screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSL or Hue, Saturation and Lightness, is an alternative to RGB colourspace and is described [here.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)

Basically, the lightness is the distance up or down the cone, the chroma or saturation is the distance along the radius and the hue is the angle of rotation around the base starting at red which is zero.

When you change the hue, you are basically sliding around the circumference of the cone to change colours. So, the 15 degrees you mention, means Photoshop is rotating all the colours and replacing them by the one 15 degrees further from red.

You can do the same thing at the commandline with **ImageMagick**, using the `-modulate` operator which modulates the lightness, saturation and hue using 3 percentages:

```
magick input.jpg -modulate 100,100,104 result.jpg
```

The 104 corresponds to 15 degress out of 360 degrees expressed as a percentage.

If you want to do it in **OpenCV**, you would convert to HSL colourspace and then take the Hue channel and, untested, I think you add 7 to it modulo 180, because it cannot represent the full 360 degrees in an unsigned char, so it uses 2 degrees for each 1 you add. I may be mistaken.

Comment: Thank you for telling about ImageMagick. I though I doomed to code it by my own.

Comment: It is an extremely powerful suite of tools - not sure why so many people think they have to write pages of Python to process images :-) Anyway, good luck with your project and feel free to come back and ask more questions if you get stuck.

Comment: There are some excellent notes by Anthony Thyssen on how to use **ImageMagick** and specifically this feature here... https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#modulate

Comment: thank you. The formula there: `modulate_arg = ( hue_angle * 100/180 ) + 100` is what I exactly need!